# Why is node.js generator not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, co

Given the following two code snippets, why is the transaction object visible in the working case but not visible in the other case?

Working case:

```
return db.transaction(function(transaction) {
  return co(function*() {
    // transaction is visible, do something with it -> works
  }
}
```

Not working case:

```
var c = co(function*() {
   // transaction is NOT visible -> does not work!
});

return db.transaction(function(transaction) {
  return c;
});
```

Is it possible to make transaction visible in the second case?

Comment: Nope, it's not in the scope of the `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is the transaction object visible in the working case but not visible in the other case?

Closures. When a function object is *created*, it just captures all the variables in the surrounding scope. In the first case, when the generator function is created, it has a variable called `transaction` in the surrounding scope. So, when it is actually invoked, the `transaction` is available in the scope.

But in the second case, when the generator function is created, `transaction` is not available.

---

To fix this, you need to explicitly pass the `transaction` object around. Maybe like this

```
function c(transaction) {
  return co(function*() {
    // transaction will be available now
  });
}

return db.transaction(function(transaction) {
  return c(transaction);
});
```

Comment: Makes sense! Is it possible to change the code slightly to make it work, e.g. calling the generator inside db.transaction(...) while still defining the function outside of it?

Comment: @Scholle Does the example in the updated answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how function scope works. In the working sample the `transaction` is a variable visible if the scope of the `db.transaction` function and all callbacks and functions within it. However when you define the generator function outside of the scope of the `db.transaction` the generator function has access only to its own variable and any variables in the parent scope.

You can find more information on function scope in javascript here for example: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: c variable is defined outside the scope, so it is used globally. Yours do not seem to make sense.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the `transaction` variable, which is not global, but local to the callback passed to the `db.transaction` function